Link and Star in P.L. Manifold
Currently I am reading a book Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology by Rourke and Sanderson.In page number 35 there is a corollary,
3.14 Corollary : If $Q \in intM $ are $(n+1)$-manifolds then $cl(M-Q)$ is an $(n+1)$-manifold.
Proof : For $p \in \partial Q $ we have $lk(p , cl(M-Q))=cl ( lk (p , M) - lk (p, Q)) $ which is a ball by 3.13 .
3.13: Suppose $B^n \subset  S^n$ is a ball in a sphere then $cl (S^n - B^n)$ is a ball .
My question is about the proof of corollary 3.14 . Here link ,  $lk(p ,cl(M-Q) ) $ is defined in manifold . In this book , any compact polyhedron is the underlying polyhedron of some simplicial complex ( Theorem 2.11 , page 16 ) and a p.l manifold M of dim n (with boundary ) is defined as a polyhedron in which each $x \in M$ has a neighborhood in $M$ which is p.l homeomorphic to an open subset of $R^n$ ( open subset of $R^{n}_{+}$). (1.8 , page 7 ).I know , link and star is defined for simplicail/cell complex . So in the proof of the corollary 3.14 , if we consider $M$ and $Q$ are compact manifold then it is okay as they have traingulation. But for general case of PL Manifold, should I consider a compact neighborhood of $p$  in $cl(M-Q)$ ?

The link is defined (as a PL homeomorphism type) for any point $a$ in any polyhedron $P$, no? It's represented by a polyhedron $L$ s.t. $N=aL$ is a cone and a neighborhood of $a$ in $P$.

@Thorgott, Okay , I understand your comment . Thanks .
